# How to send array values to servlet using NameValuePair?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I am trying to send array of boolean values to servlet.
This is what I have done so far, and I am so stuck:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    String postURL = "http://APP_NAME.appspot.com/listenforrestclient";
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        for (int i=0; i<arrBool.length; i++) {
        arrBool[i] = r.nextBoolean();
        String[] user = {"","","","","",""};
        if (arrBool[i] == true) {
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user[i]", arrBool.toString()));
        }
        else if (arrBool[i] == false) {
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user[i]", arrBool.toString()));
    }
        }
        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
        post.setEntity(ent);
        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
        if (resEntity != null) {    
            System.out.printf("RESPONSE: ", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried to do just user[i], "user[i]", user. Still couldn't find it.

and on servlet I have:

```
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException 
{
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");

    for (int i=0; i<mmaa.length; i++) {
        mmaa = req.getParameterValues("user");
        resp.getWriter().println(mmaa[i]);
    }
```

}

I searched online a lot, couldn't find anything appropriate. I would really appreciate if someone would help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the BasicNameValuePair() class  or the constructor? You have declared  `List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();` but your adding objects of BasicNameValuePair in params is BasicNameValuePair super class of NameValuePair or something?

Comment: I am able to post BasicNameValuePair("user","Available"), but that is only one value "Available" to String "user". I want to send like an array of users. BasicNameValuePair is a class which is basic implementation of NameValuePair as per the Apache HTTP Client

Comment: what does the constructor of  BasicNameValuePair looks like ????

Comment: Constructor would be BasicNameValuePair(String name, String value)

Comment: I think what you want is a list of NameValuePair and each pair will contain a username as key and the boolean data as value rite ??? check my answer.

Comment: Yes that's what I want, just the boolean data will be selected randomly. I am trying your answer, I will let you know in a minute

Answer (score 2):

You have `params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user[i]", arrBool.toString()));`

But your key is the string `"user[i]"`. Use `String.format("user[%d]", i)` instead.
So, change

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user[i]", arrBool.toString()));
```

to

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(String.format("user[%d]", i), arrBool.toString()));
```

In the servlet, you get the parameter values by doing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ...){
    String value = request.getParameter(String.format("user[%d]", i);
    //process value  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But where should I use String.format("user[%d]",i)? Also I did not understand how to Post those values to servlet so I did that loop. What loop should it be instead. Again I really appreciate your reply.

Comment: And mmaa is empty String array, I used as String[] mmaa = {"","","","","",""};

Comment: The loop is okay. You just need to be consistent with the name you use for the `BasicNameValuePair` and the name you use to retrieve the parameter in the request. See edits

Comment: Thanks. I tried according to you. Previously it was just showing null value or sometimes some garbage value like java.lang.@5444a4a. After edit, it runs well, but doesn't show any output on the servlet

Answer (score 1):

You are adding new objects of `params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user[i]", arrBool.toString()));`instead of this try doing

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(user[i].toString(), arrBool.toString()));
```

In servlet first you need to fetch the array list from the request parameter and for each value in the array list make an object of the same BeanNameValuePair and retrive values from it by using `getValue()` check Whether you are getting the values properly in the servlet Check first if your getting the ArrayList properly by debugging.

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't show anything on servlet. I thought it would work

Comment: hey i have edited my answer check your retrival and see first whether you are getting the ArrayList

Comment: check this is of help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792356/can-anyone-explain-me-this-code

Comment: Thank you Lakshmi. I understand that, but I still couldn't get output.

Comment: can you post your servlet code where u get the entity object from the request ?